# Is there a function that returns the current class/method name?

Tags: c#

In C#, is there a function that returns the current class/method name?

Comment: @zerkms : Error handling/logging.

Comment: all of this will be in the stack trace. You probably don't need to access it programmatically.

Comment: @John : 'Probably' is not good enough for me.

Comment: John is probably wrong.

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Current class name:

```
this.GetType().Name;
```

Current method name:

```
using System.Reflection;

// ...

MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
```

Since you're using this for logging purposes, you may also be interested in getting the [current stack trace](http://peterkellner.net/2009/12/21/how-to-get-a-stack-trace-from-c-without-throwing-exception/).

Comment: Current class name for non-static methods:

`this.GetType().Name;`

Current class name for static methods:

`System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name;`

Comment: What do to with respect to the "Possible System.NullReferenceException", indicated by the ReSharper for example?

Comment: @Pedro: Hmm, good question. I don't think either of those methods ever return null in practice, though...

Comment: MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name??"Unknown"; 
should handle the warning while giving the most appropriate result to the situation if in fact it ever actually does occur.

Comment: Using reflection is expensive and is sometimes unnecessary.  The question typically stems from an aversion to hard-coding the name - despite actually knowing it.  But you can let the compiler handle it by using nameof(<MethodNameHere>) in place of the string.  True, it doesn't save you from copy/paste errors where the method reference ends up being valid but its speed makes it quite useful none-the-less.

Answer (score 13):

[`System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getcurrentmethod.aspx)

Answer (score 11):

```
System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType
```

Answer (score 9):

I changed the above example a little into this piece of working example code:

```
public class MethodLogger : IDisposable
{
    public MethodLogger(MethodBase methodBase)
    {
        m_methodName = methodBase.DeclaringType.Name + "." + methodBase.Name;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} enter", m_methodName);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} leave", m_methodName);
    }
    private string m_methodName;
}

class Program
{
    void FooBar()
    {
        using (new MethodLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()))
        {
            // Write your stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Program.FooBar enter
Program.FooBar leave
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes! The MethodBase class's static GetCurrentMethod will inspect the calling code to see if it's a constructor or a normal method, and returns either a MethodInfo or a ConstructorInfo.

This namespace is a part of the reflection API, so you can basically discover everything that the run-time can see by using it.

Here you will find an exhaustive description of the API:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.aspx

If you don't feel like looking through that entire library here is an example I cooked up:

```
namespace Canvas
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod());
        DiscreteMathOperations viola = new DiscreteMathOperations();
        int resultOfSummation = 0;
        resultOfSummation = viola.ConsecutiveIntegerSummation(1, 100);
        Console.WriteLine(resultOfSummation);
    }
}

public class DiscreteMathOperations
{
    public int ConsecutiveIntegerSummation(int startingNumber, int endingNumber)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod());
        int result = 0;
        result = (startingNumber * (endingNumber + 1)) / 2;
        return result;
    }
}    
}
```

The output of this code will be:

```
Void Main<System.String[]> // Call to GetCurrentMethod() from Main.
Int32 ConsecutiveIntegerSummation<Int32, Int32> //Call from summation method.
50 // Result of summation.
```

Hope I helped you!

JAL

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current class name, but I can't think of anyway to get the current method name. Though, the names of methods for the current can be obtained.

```
string className = this.GetType().FullName;
System.Reflection.MethodInfo[] methods = this.GetType().GetMethods();
foreach (var method in methods)
    Console.WriteLine(method.Name);
```